# Get value of dynamically created textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to dynamically add rows to a table, I create some textboxes in each row, I've added an onkeyup event to one of my textboxes:

```
               var myTotal = "1";
           var spanTotal = document.createElement("span");
           spanTotal.innerHTML = "<input style=\"width:50px\" type=\"text\" name=\"total\" value=" + myTotal + ">";


spanCount.onkeyup = function ()
{
alert(spanTotal.innerHTML);
    };
```

then I add this span (which is rendered as an HTML textbox) to my table row. I want to have value of my dynamically created textbox, but whenever I change this textbox, initial value of this textbox is displayed in alert box (i.e. 1). Initial value of this textbox is "1", but when I change it (for instance type a 0 in textbox), again "1" is displyaed in alert box. I want to have value of my dynamically created textbox, should I give an ID to my span? how should I define spanCount.onkeyup function? where should it be defined so that I can have exact value of this textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8X7N/). You can get value of input box using childNodes. There are other problems in code you were using `spanCount` istead of `spanTotal`.

Modified code:

```
var myTotal = "1";
var spanTotal = document.createElement("span");
spanTotal.innerHTML = "<input style=\"width:50px\" type=\"text\" name=\"total\" value=" + myTotal + ">";
document.body.appendChild(spanTotal);

spanTotal.onkeyup = function() {
    alert(spanTotal.childNodes[0].value);
};​
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful! It save me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Below modified code maybe can solve your problem:

```
var myTotal = 1;

/* object creation */
var span = document.createElement('span');

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('name', 'total');
input.setAttribute('style', 'width:50px;');
input.setAttribute('value', myTotal);

// append each object to respective container
span.appendChild(input);
document.appendChild(span);

/* event handler */
input.onkeyup = function(){
  alert(this.value);
}
```